# skrollr width infinitescroll doesn't work

Tags: infinite-scroll, skrollr

I'm using great plugin skrollr and infinitescroll together, however, skrollr stops when other posts are loaded.

The skrollr works only in the height before other posts loaded.

Is it possible to make it works with infinite scroll?

Now the HTML is like this.

```
<div class="scroll r r1" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 200px;;"></div>
<div class="scroll r r2" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {     var s = skrollr.init(); });
</script>
```

Thank you.

**Edit 1**:

```
<div class="scroll r r1" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 200px;;"></div>
<div class="scroll r r2" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {     var s = skrollr.init(); });
</script>

html of new elements whose class is .eachnews

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).call(function() {     skrollrInstance.refresh(.eachnews); });
</script>
```

the other one is like this

```
<div class="scroll r r1" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 200px;;"></div>
<div class="scroll r r2" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 400px;"></div>

<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/skrollr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {     var s = skrollr.init(); skrollrInstance.refresh(.eachnews);});
</script>
```

the another one is like this

```
<div class="scroll r r1" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 200px;;"></div>
<div class="scroll r r2" data-0="background-position:center 100px;" data-end="background-position:center 400px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(window).load(function() {     var s = skrollr.init(); });

jQuery('.eachnews').load(function() {     skrollrInstance.refresh('.eachnews'); });

</script>
```

I'm very sorry for my technique, but I really appreciate if you teach me how to make it work.

Comment: After loading new elements, call `skrollrInstance.refresh(arrayOfNewElements)`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt replay.
I tried few time, but didn't work.
I'm very sorry for my poor acknowledgement.
Please check what I did below.(sorry I couldn't understand how to type and linebreak words here properly. )

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support. I made it.

After loading new elements, I needed to call `skrollr.get().refresh();` at all.

`skrollrInstance.refresh(arrayOfNewElements)` and `skrollr.get().refresh(arrayOfNewElements);` didn't work somehow.

I hope this will help somebody.

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('.news').infinitescroll({
        navSelector  : "div.nav-previous",
        nextSelector : "div.nav-previous a",
        itemSelector : ".eachnews",
        bufferPx: 500,
loading: {
        img:"url/images/loading.gif",
        speed: 'fast',
        finishedMsg:"<div class='done'><p>no more entries</p></div>",
        msgText:""
    }
    },
function(arrayOfNewElems){
skrollr.get().refresh();
});
});
```

Thank you.